# Same template, different code?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way to have the same template type while having different code by changing the value passed? ie:

```
template <bool>
class container;
```

And having `container<true>` generate different code than `container<false>`?

If not are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of `template`s. Note, however, that `container<true>` and `container<false>` are *not* the same type.

Comment: I don't quite understand the downvote. How is this question not useful? (low research efforts may be, but still a lot more useful than many others appearing here).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. This is called *template specialization*. You can write code like this:

```
template <bool> class container {
    /* Implementation for true */
};

template <> class container<false> {
    /* Implementation for false */
};
```

Now, if you instantiate `container<true>`, it will pick the top version because the bottom one is not applicable. If you instantiate `container<false>`, then the bottom one will be chosen, since both versions are applicable, but the bottom is more specialized.

The implementations here can be completely different. There's no requirement that they have anything in common. This is often used to implement compile-time computation. Look up *template metaprogramming* for more information.

Comment: "Look up template metaprogramming for more information" is too much, here

Comment: @DieterLücking Agreed. I was mentioning it mostly in the context of "to implement compile-time computation," and since I figured it might be a good starting point if the OP was curious in learning more about how template specialization can be used.